# Use operators on time()

Tags: php, time, operators

I'm coding a delete and edit function for my guestbook and I only want the users to be able to change their posts in 30 minutes time. As I understand I cant use operators on time, but I don't know how else to do it. i hope someone can help. The code looks like this now, and I need to change the time-check (last in the if statement).

```
$delete_time = $_GET["time"];
$max_delete_time = date("H:i", strtotime("$delete_time + 30 minutes"));

if ($delete_ip == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] AND $delete_date == date("F d, Y") AND $delete_time <= $max_delete_time){
```

Answer (score 0):

30 minutes is 1800 seconds, you can simply compare if $delete_time is less than your created_time + 1800 (you seem to be comparing deleted_time <= deleted_time + 30 minutes which will always return true, make sure it's deleted_time <= created_time + 30 minutes or 1800).

Comment: Yeah I just saw that mistake in my code.. it should be this:

$current_time <= $max_delete_time)

But still, can I use the operator for this? I mean, the time looks like this 10:31.. so is it possible to do as follows:

if(10:30 >= 10:41);

Comment: $max_delete_time = strtotime('+30 minutes', $delete_time);

This'll get you the timestamp (integer), you can then compare it.